# MongoDB select by condition of any element of array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I just started learning Mongo after using SQL, what if true way to select object by condition of any of "grades" elements?
For example, choose all objects that have any of grades greater than 10 and lesser than 50. The number of elements in the array can be different

```
{
  "address": "Moscow"
  "grades": [
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": 1419897600000
      },
      "grade": "A",
      "score": 8
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": 1404172800000
      },
      "grade": "B",
      "score": 23
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use` $elemMatch`

Comment: @nimrodserok , this one doesnt work: db.employees.find({ grades: { $elemMatch: { score : { $lt: 20  }}});

Comment: Just missed bracket

Comment: Just of note - `$elemMatch` is required when there are multiple conditions (including both `$gt` and `$lt`) in the predicate filters on the array. So you definitely need it for what was described in the question, but not for the simpler example above in the comments. More info [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition)